# Calling activity for result from dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, android-alertdialog, onactivityresult

i'd like to call an `activity` for a result. With a button within the calling `activity` it's no problem but i'd like to call the sub-activity from a dialog:

```
public class AddDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setNeutralButton("Add", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

The sub-activity is called and closed as expected but `onActivityResult` isn't called.
Is it because `startActivityForResult` is called from an `Fragment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` use: 
`getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`

And see if it works.